# sudo -u not preserving the scripts sourced in my shell

Tags: bash, sudo

I have a bash script which add some functions to my shell. The script is as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function invoke_echo() {
    echo "test"
}
```

when I source this script to my shell and call `invoke_echo` method, it print "test" as expected.

However when I run it as a different user using `sudo -u`, an error is thrown

```
sudo -u some_user invoke_echo
```

All these instructions were invoked from the same shell session. The entire shell session looks like this,

```
[ Tue Jan 23,03:01:49 - ~ ]
vjoshi: cat test_echo.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function invoke_echo() {
    echo "test"
}

[ Tue Jan 23,03:01:59 - ~ ]
vjoshi: invoke_echo
-bash: invoke_echo: command not found

[ Tue Jan 23,03:02:04 - ~ ]
vjoshi: source test_echo.sh

[ Tue Jan 23,03:02:11 - ~ ]
vjoshi: invoke_echo
test

[ Tue Jan 23,03:02:14 - ~ ]
vjoshi: sudo -u some_user invoke_echo
sudo: invoke_echo: command not found
```

I want to call `invoke_echo` as some_user but I want to source the test_echo.sh before sudo -u since I am using `invoke_echo` at some other places in my current script as well. Doing source of the script multiple times does not look tidy to me

Comment: AFAIK you get a new shell as a different user with `sudo`, so nothing of the old shell settings carries over. It would be quite confusing to have e..g., `$HOME` still point to the previous user's home.

Comment: Good explanation [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/549140/why-doesnt-sudo-e-preserve-the-function-environment-variables-exported-by-ex), long story short is that `sudo` works very hard to disallow the export of functions to the new shell for security reasons. You can work around it on some versions with enough effort but make sure you really understand why it's frowned upon before doing so.

Comment: Also note that functions aren't inherited by child processes by default so you'd need to put `export -f invoke_echo` in your `test_echo.sh` even if you were just trying to pass the function to a child bash process.

Comment: Side note: when you use that to add the function to your current shell, the shebang line doesn't do anything useful for you, other than simply conveying to humans that the content is meant to be interpreted by bash.

Comment: @Robert This has less to do with preserving your shell's environment and more to do with the fact that `sudo` executes *executable files*, and does not interact with your shell at all.